# CSS footer at the bottom of page won't scroll down if body gets longer

Tags: css

> EDIT: using `position:fixed` for pageHeader, pageBody, and pageFooter
>   (and then correcting their positions) did it for me. Thanks guys!

I'm working on an Android web application using HTML and CSS. I currently have this:

```
#container {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}

#pageHeader {
 color:<%=foreColor%>;
}

#pageBody {
 padding-bottom:100px;
}

#pageFooter {
 position:static;
 clear:both;
 bottom:0;
 height:5%;
}
```

I managed to stick the footer to the bottom of the page using this, but when the body gets longer than the page height, the footer doesn't scroll down to the bottom of the page (it sticks to the bottom of the page height) therefore part of the body that is lower than the screen overlaps it.

I'm using this HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="pageHeader"></div>
  <div id="pageBody"></div>
</div>
<div id="pageFooter"></div>
```

[I also have a header, body, footer ids within pageBody if that affects anything]

Comment: As for your edit you said "and then correcting their positions". Can you elaborate? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Kleigh It's been a few years so I don't know exactly how, but I think it was the paddings/margins, or how far each element should be from top/bottom. What issues are you seeing after setting `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryan Faits CSS Sticky footer has long been the standard way of achieving a sticky footer.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Unless I'm misunderstanding you and you want to make a fixed footer (where it would be at the bottom of the screen all the time)

In which case just set `position:fixed` instead of `static`

Comment: I currently have the footer at the bottom of the screen but when the page size gets longer than the screen size, the footer doesn't go down to the bottom of the page, but sticks to the bottom of the screen. Therefore, when I scroll down, the footer stays where it is and the body overlaps it.

Comment: I think the words your looking for are `window` and `document`. The window is the visible area of a web page so fixing something to the bottom of the window would be like the chatbar on the bottom of a Facebook page. For this you would use `position:fixed` where `bottom:0` refers to the bottom of the window. If your looking to make sure that there's never any whitespace at the bottom o the document, use Ryan Faits sticky footer.

Comment: 404 on your url

Answer (score 0):

Is this all your CSS?

Your `pageFooter` should naturally be at the bottom of the page using this CSS, as the `div`s follow each other in order and are not being removed from the page flow.

That said, `position:relative;` without any positioning and `position:static` in this instance do not seem to be doing anything.  Maybe they are causing the mobile browser to choke.  Try removing them.

Comment: No, I have more CSS under that but all for fonts and colors, nothing about positioning, would that matter?